# Will humid air mitigate airborn dust due to neutralization of static electricity?

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

I have came to understand that humid air will help prevent electrostatic forces that can propel dust and cause it to cling to surfaces.

My first question: is this above statement true?

If the answer to the first question is true, then please continue: I have attempted to find designs for the various types of humidifiers but have not been successful. After examining a simple facial steamer and using some thought experiments, I have a crude design to propose, but am open to any other proposed designs reasonable for DIY construction. I understand there are many method to vaporize water.

My current design is to have a stainless steel, rectangular tank with all sides enclosed and two holes drilled in the top. One hole will be used for inbound air while the other hole will be connected to a fan which will pull humid air out. On the bottom of the tank will be attached a flexible silicone heater that will heat the water to X temperature and enhance evaporation.

My second question: is this design effective?

My third question: given the simplicity of the proposed design, are any other designs better for DIY?

Comment: A huge unusual thunderstorm that hit Athens Greece a few days ago rained red dust from the Sahara so that the torrents in the streets were red. The clouds had both humidity and dust , and there was an unprecedented cascade of cloud-cloud lightining. The meteorologists said that the electric part of the  storm was so strong because of the static from the dust in the middle of the clouds! It aint simple.